# How to properly terminate a graph that contains a loop?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a `SinkShape` graph with a loop inside:

```
source.take(10) ~> merge ~> process ~> split ~> out
                   merge.preferred  <~ split
```

Internally I make sure that for each `Stream` element the number of the loops is limited.

I materialize this graph with the following code:

```
val result: Future[Int] = Source.fromGraph(graph).runWith(Sink.fold(...))
```

Now I try to obtain the value of this `Future`, but the `onComplete` callback is never invoked. The original Source within the graph should terminate properly, as I've added `.take(10)` statement.

I've also tried to remove the loop, and the `Future` is generated as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Merge` stage (and `MergePreferred` as well) can complete eagerly or not.
In other words, you can tell your stage to complete when *any* of its inputs completes, or when *all* of its inputs complete.

In your case you need an eager completion, as one of the 2 inputs (namely the one marked as preferred) will never complete because of the loopback.

`Merge` stages expose the completion behaviour in a boolean flag, which defaults to false (see the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.17/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#mergePreferred) for more info). Try to change it to true.

```
val merge = b.add(MergePreferred(secondaryPorts = 2, eagerComplete = true))
```